# Is there a good way to handle POST when logged out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Create POST action that does not have a GET action inside my controller. In my AccountController I have a Login action that return to the ReturnUrl when pass to the query. The problem is that since Create does not have a Get action, I get a 404.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You might want to look at [Explained: Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) which explains basically how ASP.Net froms authentication works, then use reflector to disassemble classes `FormsAuthenticationModule` and `FormsAuthentication` under namespace `System.Web.Security` in `System.Web.dll` to learn how ASP.Net Forms Authentication works and rewrite it to achieve the best effect.

  Basically you'll need to modify the code that does the redirecting to add the following features

  1. Generate a random key, like `System.Guid.NewGuid()`, extract the post data and store it together with the request url in `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[<key>]`
  2. Change the redirection url from `<Path to login page.aspx>?ReturnUrl=<Url>` to `<Path to login page.aspx?RequestId=<key>`
  3. After the authentication, redirect according to the cached value. If there is any post data, generated a auto post form (in HTML) and return it to the client so that the original request can continue.

  `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage` and `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl` are possibly what you need to edit. You can extra the request variable using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request`

  This can be tedious and delicate work since Microsoft code is ever so complicated, and can prove impossible if you cannot obtain either the .Net source code (I'm not sure if Microsoft still offers it) or a (free) Reflector license.
- Alternatively, you can write a custom IHttpModule doing the following:

  1. Checks on every request to see if it is that post action in question, and if it is
  2. Extracts the post data if not authenticated and stores the data in the `Session` variable

  Then,

  1. Create a get action for the post action that returns a auto post back page, just like point 3 in the first bullet.
  2. Add the module to you application. Make sure it is executed before `FormsAuthenticationModule` or it won't work.

  You can start with [Walkthrough: Creating and Registering a Custom HTTP Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx).

  This method can cause some problems if you user decides to do multiple posting at the same time, as the second request will overwrite data in `Session`.

The above two choices are methods of directly dealing with you problem. It might be easier if you changed the Post controller into Get. The above methods are not worthy unless you have a great number of pages experiencing the same problem or you want to experiment with ASP.Net.